# send files from google drive to dropbox with google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, dropbox-api, drive

I've been searching how to do this, but i didn't find anything. After a while, i came up with the script i'll post as an answer.
I'm posting this for myself and anyone who might find it useful.

You'll need to get a dropbox access token, that can be obtained after creating a dropbox app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function send2dropbox(file) {
  var dropboxTOKEN = 'XXXxxx';

  var path = '/somePath/' + file.getName();
  var dropboxurl = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/save_url';
  var fileurl = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file.getId(); 

  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + dropboxTOKEN,
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  var payload = {
    "path": path,
    "url": fileurl
  }
  var options = {      
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)    
  }; 

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dropboxurl, options);  
  return response;  
}
```

You can find an example [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183615/upload-file-to-dropbox-with-google-app-script-using-save-url-from-dropbox-api/46201086#46201086)

Comment: Note that this codes uses Dropbox API v1, which is [deprecated and being retired soon](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). You should use [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead. The relevant endpoint in this case is [/2/save_url](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-save_url).